# Export personal Outlook 2016 contacts, excluding the global address list

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, contacts, exchange-2010

In Outlook 2016, how do I export contacts from an outlook profile, while excluding contacts that appear on the global address list? I'm trying to include only contacts that have been added manually.

I have access to exchange and powershell, if need be.

Comment: What have you tried so far? As far as I know this is the standard behavior when you choose to export from outlook. What format are you trying to export to?

Comment: I've tried going to File>Open & Export>Import/Export, and exporting the Contacts folder, but it's full of stuff from the global address list.